# React-Native for loop using FlatList is giving error

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am new in programming. I would like to render list dynamically. The parent component Navbar has state with Food Type category like Mexican, Chinese. Each of the FoodTypes have their respective Menu

What I like is to render first FoodType and then its respective Menu in FlatList. The data is saved in Navbar Component. I can render the FoodType using FlatList, but problem is in for loop logic.The for loop is giving me error.
Please see the sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-lamarr-p8mq3

The relevant code is below(line 130-154), in Menu Component

```
render() {
   
    return (
      <View className="container-fluid">
    
    <Text> Here use Flatlist</Text>
    
    
    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.Objs_Type.length; i++) {
    <FlatList 
    data={this.props.Objs_Type}
    renderItem={({item})=>
    <Text>{item.FoodType[i]}</Text>
    <Text>{item.Menu[i]}</Text>
   }
   keyExtractor={(item,index)=>item.id}
   /> 
  };
 
  
    </View>

    ) 
  }
```

Comment: I thank you all for the valuable comments. I got what i wanted. Please see code

Answer (score 0):

use nested flat list one vertical and horizontal flatlist to get the ui

check below code
snack: https://snack.expo.io/@ashwith00/list

code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

const data = [
  {
    title: 'Chinese',
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  },
  {
    title: 'Mexican',
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  },
  {
    title: 'Indian',
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  },
  {
    title: 'Indian',
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  },
];
// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  const renderCategory = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', height: 200, marginBottom: 20 }}>
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(_, i) => i.toString()}
        data={item.data}
        horizontal
        renderItem={renderBar}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      />
    </View>
  );

  const renderBar = ({ item }) => (
    <View
      style={{
        height: '100%',
        width: 240,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        marginRight: 10,
      }}
    />
  );
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(_, i) => i.toString()}
        renderItem={renderCategory}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But i need to render first Chinese from FoodType, then its Menu, then Mexixan frm FoodType and then its Menu. So i have to iterate each of the item

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `render()` function in this way:

```js
render() {

    return (
        <View className="container-fluid">

            <Text> Here use Flatlist</Text>

            <FlatList
                data={this.props.Objs_Type}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <View>
                        <Text>{item.FoodType}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.Menu}</Text>
                    </View>
                )}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
            />

        </View>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error which I saw in the sandbox link you provided is "Unexpected token". Whenever you get this error, it is most likely due to a syntactic mistake. In your case, it was missing curly braces around your for-loop. Remember whenever you embed any JavaScript code into a JSX block, make sure you encapsulate the JavaScript codes within curly braces.

```
return (
   <jsx-code>
     {
        some-js-logic like if-else, etc.
     }
   </jsx-code>
)
```

Now in your case, even if you add a pair of braces, it won't work, because the for loop in JSX won't work that way. More on this in the first link which I provided at the end.

And to solve your problem, you don't have to use a for-loop at all. The `FlatList` component accepts the array in its `data` param. So you don't have to loop through the array. All you got to do is use the items of this array to render your own UI. Here's a sample which is the simplest representation of your code snippet.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View className="container-fluid">
        <Text> Here use Flatlist </Text>
        {
          this.generateFlatList(this.props.Objs_Type)
        }
      </View>
    );
  }

  generateFlatList(objsTypes) {
    console.log(objsTypes);
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={objsTypes}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.FoodType}</Text>}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    );
  }
```

Here are some links which might help you learn more about using for-loop in React JSX and FlatList component:

- https://flaviocopes.com/react-how-to-loop/
- https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But i need to render first Chinese from FoodType, then its Menu, then Mexican frm FoodType and then its Menu. So i have to iterate each of the item

Comment: @salabb I think the [SelectionList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist) component should suffice your requirement. Here is an [example](https://snack.expo.io/?session_id=snack-session-inSYVuZ__&preview=true&platform=web&iframeId=jvdt80pl91&supportedPlatforms=ios,android,web&name=SectionList%20Example&description=Example%20usage&waitForData=true) using SelectionList.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the valuable comments. Helped me learned alot. If someone is interested, below is the corrected code

```
  <View className="container-fluid">
        <Text> Here use Flatlist</Text>

        <FlatList
          data={this.props.Objs_Type}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <Text>{item.FoodType}</Text>
              {item.Menu.map(e => (
                <Text>{e}</Text>
              ))}
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
      </View>
```

renderItem if you put two tags like two Texts, it will iterate it automatially. So in my case, i had two items in Food_Type and 3 Menu items in each of Food_Type. if you just use two Text each for Food_Type and Menu, it will first print Chinese, then the array ofMenu of Chinese. To display Menu vertically i had to use map .